# Javascript - Compare without typecasting to boolean

Tags: javascript

In other languages I have two sets of operators, `or` and `||`, which typecast differently. Does Javascript have a set of operators to compare and return the original object, rather than a boolean value?

I want to be able to return whichever value is defined, with a single statement like `var foo = bar.name or bar.title`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is only one set of boolean operators (`||`, `&&`)  and they already do that.

```
var bar = {
    name: "",
    title: "foo"
};

var foo = bar.name || bar.title;

alert(foo); // alerts 'title'
```

Of course you have to keep in mind [which values evaluate to false](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_9.2).

Comment: That's it. I had something evaluating to false when I didn't think it would. Whoops.

Answer (score 2):

```
var foo = (bar.name != undefined) ? bar.name : 
          ((bar.title != undefined) ? bar.title : 'error');
```

Answer (score 2):

`var foo = bar.name || bar.title;`

It returns the first defined object.

If none of both is defined, `undefined` is returned.

Answer (score 1):

I either completely missunderstood the question or it's just straighforward like you mentioned:

```
var foo = bar.name || bar.title;
```

if `bar.name` contains any *truthy* value it's assigned into `foo`, otherwise `bar.title` is assigned.

for instance:

```
var bar = {
    name: null,
    title: 'Foobar'
};

var foo = bar.name || bar.title
console.log( foo ); // 'Foobar'
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript behaves exactly like you want:

```
var a = [1, 2],
    b = [3, 4];

console.log(a || b); //will output [1, 2]
a = 0;
console.log(a || b); //will outout [3, 4]
```

If you whant to typecast to boolean you can use double negative operator:

```
console.log(!![1, 2]); //will output true
console.log(!!0); //will output false
```